# Insert XML content to php

Tags: php, xml

Can anyone please help me fetch an email address from an XML file & insert it to a php code? Please find the codes below.

**XML CODE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
<data>
<emailaddress>info@website.com</emailaddress>
</data>
</document>
```

**PHP CODE**

```
if($_POST){
$to_email = "<?php $xml=simplexml_load_file("data.xml"); echo $xml->data->emailaddress;?>";
}
```

This php code does not pull the email address from the xml file. Can anyone suggest me a fix?

Thanks heaps in advance!

Cheers
David

Comment: `if($_POST){
$to_email = "<?php $xml=simplexml_load_file("data.xml"); echo $xml->data[0]->emailaddress;?>";
}`   try this

Comment: Seems like simplexml_load_file expects a URI.  Will it accept a plain filename?  If so, what directory does it assume?

Comment: @ S N Tiwari

Thanks. But it didn't work!

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b

it does accept the file, data.xml is in the same directory.

I can't figure out how to add the below code within `$to_email =""`

Code:

`<?php $xml=simplexml_load_file("data.xml"); echo $xml->data[0]->emailaddress;?>`

Comment: assuming your code is close to correct (because i don't know php) it may be that you needed 'document' after the $xml or even in place of it. I mean the document tag is missing in other words.

Comment: @Clay Ferguson
Cheers mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one (tested):

```
<?php
    if($_POST){ 
    $xml=simplexml_load_file("data.xml"); 

    echo $xml->data[0]->emailaddress;

    }

?>
```

---

Or Try like your code :

```
<?php
    if($_POST){
    $xml=simplexml_load_file("data.xml");
    $to_email =$xml->data[0]->emailaddress;
    echo $to_email;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you heaps!!! This worked..

`<?php
    if($_POST){
    $xml=simplexml_load_file("data.xml");
    $to_email =$xml->data[0]->emailaddress;
    echo $to_email;
    }
?>`